# Views Positions Reset when Keyboard Shows

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Dears,

I have the following scenario:

- I have two views inside a screen "Upper View and Lower View"
- The Upper view is taking the whole screen and the lower one is not visible since its down "Its Y Axis starts from the End of the other view Height"
- When the user presses a button i move both views up to make the lower view visible and the upper one hidden.

All that works great, **Here is the problem:**

There is a text box in the lower View, When the user selects it to add text, the keyboard shows and simply resets all the views to their initial positions which ruins everything "The Upper View shows again.

Here is the code I used to move the views:

```
@IBAction func signInWithEmailPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.topView.center.y -= self.topView.bounds.height
        self.bottomView.center.y -= self.topView.bounds.height
        }, completion: { finished in
            if(finished) {

                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
    })
}
```

Don't know why it keeps resetting all the views. Your help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: are you using AutoLayout/ constraints?

Comment: When you called `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` you updated aytolayout. For your case you need change constraint and in animation block call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: I did not put any constraints explicitly on the controls, but yeah the whole project is using autolayout

Comment: @iSashok even if I removed self.view.layoutIfNeeded() it goes with the same behavior because There isnt any constrains for any controls

Comment: @Mostafa Mohamed Raafat if you use autolayout, compiler will add some constraint to views by default. Try to disable autolayout and change the frame in animation block

Answer (score -1):

Try This ..............

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad() 

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("makeSpaceForKeyboard:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("makeSpaceForKeyboard:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}

deinit{
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}



func makeSpaceForKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {

    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight:CGFloat = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().size.height
    let duration:Double = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double

    if notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification && keyboardIsVisible == false{

        keyboardIsVisible = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
            var frame = self.view.frame
            frame.size.height = frame.size.height - keyboardHeight
            self.view.frame = frame
        })

    } else if keyboardIsVisible == true && notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification{

    }else {
        keyboardIsVisible = false

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
            var frame = self.view.frame
            frame.size.height = frame.size.height + keyboardHeight
            self.view.frame = frame
        })
    }
}
```